# Как отдавать другой index c поддомена?

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Как я могу настроить роутинг в koa-router чтобы на запрос основного домена отдавался один index.html, а с m.domen.com - index.html мобильной версии.

Comment: p.s. учтите еще что `ctx.request.origin` свойства не будет для localhost, так что лучше используйте второй вариант, он более стабильный, потому что браузер всегда шлет юзер агент в запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст содержит в себе всю необходимую информацию. Первый вариант - это проверять наличие домена в `ctx.request.origin`:

```
const router = new Router();

router.get('/', (ctx) => {
  ctx.type = 'html';

  if (ctx.request.origin.indexOf('m.domen.com') > -1) {
    ctx.body = createReadStream('./path-to-mobile-index.html');
  } else {
    ctx.body = createReadStream('./path-to-desktop-index.html');
  }
});
```

Второй вариант это использование какой-то библиотеки для распознавания мобильного устройства, `mobile-detect` например:

```
const MobileDetect = require('mobile-detect');

const router = new Router();

router.get('/', (ctx) => {
  ctx.type = 'html';

  const md = new MobileDetect(ctx.request.header['user-agent']);
  if (md.mobile()) {
    ctx.body = createReadStream('./path-to-mobile-index.html');
  } else {
    ctx.body = createReadStream('./path-to-desktop-index.html');
  }
});
```